# 'cout': is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++

I've looked at a lot of solutions for this problem but none have worked

Main:

```
#include "player.cpp"
#include "player.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
     player p;
     SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
     for (;;) {
          p.move()
     }
}
```

player.h:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

class player {
    private:
        short x = 0;
        short y = 0;
    public:
        void move() {
            std::cout << x << '\n';
            x += 1;
        }
};

#endif
```

player.cpp:

```
#include "player.h"

#include <iostream>
```

It keeps saying cout is not a member of std, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Never ever do that: `#include "player.cpp"` That's wrong!

Comment: You need to `#include <iostream>` in player.h if you are going to put calls to std::cout in the header.

Comment: Not what you asked, but if you're on Windows, `int main()` might blow up in your face. SDL normally expects `int main(int, char **)`.

Comment: Side note: If the cpp file doesn't implement anything, leave it out. Save you a few seconds when compiling.

Comment: @user4581301, I disagree. It ensures the header compiles with no prior includes before other code starts using it. (You could also make an argument to move that to the testing section of the project.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `player.h` file does not have a `#include <iostream>` in it.

You have two choices:

1. Make every header file able to stand on its own.
2. Ensure that you document and meet the pre-requisites for every header file you include.

You have done neither of these things.

Comment: Also, OP probably doesn't want to be defining `move` in `player.h` (just adding the include will result in duplicate definitions at link time)

Comment: My rule of thumb is to strongly prefer option 1. People usually don't read documentation until it's too late.